# Why is the Transfer Speed so much fluctuating with my USB SSD? Transfer of ISO file on Win10

Tags: windows-10, ssd, speed, usb-storage

When I write an ISO file to my USB2 SSD, the transfer speed varies a lot. It starts fast, goes down to 0, appears hanging for a while and continues with kind of fast bursts.

Why is the Transfer Speed so much fluctuating with my USB SSD?
Is it a kind of cache being filled and then slowly written away by the SSD?

SSD is an older 240GB SanDisk SATA 6GB/s

[image: Write]

Answer (score 2):

You are right - you're seeing the memory cache of Windows in action.

Here is how it goes :

- Windows reads quickly data from the input file and fills up the memory
- Windows flushes some of the data to the disk
- Once enough free memory exists it's filled again.

Comment: But should I not see then kind of repeating waves of the same behaviour all the time until all data are written?

Comment: The waves should smooth out somewhat as writing out approaches full speed and everything stabilizes with a more-or-less the same speed. There might be hiccups when Windows executes tasks that have resource precedence, or if some task takes up and then releases lots of memory. Most of the memory is used for both programs and cache, so the speed and the available memory are a function of what else Windows is doing.